# Meaning of G(k) being dense in G for an algebraic group G/k

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over a field $k$ of characteristic 0. I have read that: if $G$ is connected, then $G(k)$ is dense in $G$ for the Zariski topology. I do not understand what kind of density this might be since $G(k)$ is abstractly defined as the set of morphisms $\text{Spec}(k) \to G$. If $G$ is an affine variety in $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ for instance, one might think of $G(k)$ as a subset of $k^n$. But how does this connect to the abstract definition of $G$ as a scheme or as a functor from $k$-algebras to groups? I do not see a direct relation or any mean to relate the group $G(k)$ (a set of points) to the abstract scheme (or functor) $G$, let alone saying that $G(k)$ is dense in $G$ for the Zariski topology. How is this topology even defined on $G(k)$ and how is $G(k)$ even a subset of $G$? Could someone please resolve this issue for me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It's good to learn the functor-of-points approach inside out, but for affine algebraic groups we can use embeddings to get our head around things.

First, $G$ had better be affine or this is utterly false (for instance an elliptic curve might have only one rational point). Once you know $G$ is affine, you can pick an embedding in affine space and drop the functor-of-points abstraction.

Then $G(k)$ just means the points whose coordinates are all in $k$, and the claim is that this subset of $G(\overline{k})$ is dense in it, for the usual zariski topology.

Comment: +1 no disrespect meant in posting an alternative answer.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}$$\newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{O}}$$\newcommand{\mf}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}$While **hunter**'s answer is perfectly fine, I do think it's worth phrasing it in a way that is independent of embedding.

The point is the following:

> **Fact:** *Let $X$ be a scheme, $A$ ring, and $L$ a field. Suppose that $X$ and $L$ have the structure of a $\Spec(A)$-scheme. Then, there is
> a natural equality (really bijection)
> $$\mathrm{Hom}_{\Spec(A)}(\Spec(L),X)=\left\{(x,\varphi):\begin{aligned}(1)&\quad
>  x\in X\\ (2)&\quad \varphi:k(x)\to L\text{ is an }\\ &\quad A\text{-algebra
>  homomorphism}\end{aligned}\right\}$$*

Here $k(x)$ is the residue field of $x$.

*Proof:* Let us use $p$ to denote the single point of $\Spec(L)$ (as a topological space it's one point). Suppose first that $f:\Spec(L)\to X$ is a morphism of schemes over $\Spec(A)$. Then, $x:=f(p)$ is a point of $X$. By the definition of a morphism of schemes one has a local ring map $f^\sharp_x:\h_{X,x}\to \h_{\Spec(L),p}=L$. But, since this map is local and $(0)$ is the maximal ideal of $L$ we see that $\ker(f_x^\sharp)=(f^\sharp_x)^{-1}((0))=\mf{m}_x$ (this last ideal being hte maximal ideal of $\h_{X,x}$). In particular, $f_x^\sharp$ factorizes uniquely through $\h_{X,x}/\mf{m}_x=k(x)$. Thus, from $f$ we get the pair $(x,f_x^\sharp)$. Conversely, if we have a pair $(x,\varphi)$ we get a morphism $\Spec(\varphi):\Spec(L)\to \Spec(k(x))$. But, note that we have obvious morphisms of $\Spec(A)$-schemes

$$\Spec(k(x))\to \Spec(\h_{X,x})\to X$$

where the first is the one coming from the quotient map $\h_{X,x}\to k(x)$ and the second is the tautological one (i.e. for any affine open $\Spec(B)$ of $X$ containing $x$ there is the natural map $\Spec(\h_{X,x})=\Spec(B_\mf{q})\to \Spec(B)\to X$ where $\mf{q}$ is the prime ideal of $B$ corresponding to $x$--this composition can be checked to be indpendent of the choice of $B$). We then get a morphism $\Spec(L)\to X$ as the composition

$$\Spec(L)\xrightarrow{\Spec(\varphi)}\Spec(k(x))\to\Spec(\h_{X,x})\to X$$

It's easy to check that these two associations are inverse to one another. $\blacksquare$

What's the upshot of this?

> **Corollary:** *Let $X$ be a scheme over $\Spec(k)$. Then, there is a natural equality (bijection)
> $$X(k):=\mathrm{Hom}_{\Spec(k)}(\Spec(k),X)=\{x\in X:k(x)=k\}$$*

*Proof:* Applying the last fact we see that $X(k)$ is in bijection with points $(x,\varphi)$ where $x$ is in $X$ and $\varphi:k(x)\to k$ is a $k$-morphism. But, note that there is a $k$-morphism $k(x)\to k$ if and only if $k(x)=k$ (more precisely the natural morphism $k\to k(x)$ is an isomorphism) in which case it's unique. Thus, we get our result! $\blacksquare$

In particular, for any scheme $X$ over $\Spec(k)$ we see that we can naturally view $X(k)$ as a **subset** of $X$. In particular, to say that $X(k)$ is dense in $X$ means that the subset $X(k)$ is dense in the topological space $X$ (the scheme $X$ considered with the Zariski topology).

The following is a good exercise:

> **Exercise:** *Let $X$ be an affine scheme which is of finite type over $\Spec(k)$. Choose a closed embedding $X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_k=:\Spec(k[T_1,\ldots,T_n])$
> over $\Spec(k)$. Then, $X(k)$ (as described above) agrees with $X\cap
>  k^n$ where $k^n\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_k$ is the usual embedding of sets
> (i.e. $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in k^n$ corresponds to the maximal ideal
> $(T_1-x_1,\ldots,T_n-x_n)$).*

This shows the connection to **hunter**'s answer.

Then, your result more accurately/generally is the following:

> **Theorem ([1, Theorem 17.93]):** *Let $k$ be an infinite perfect field. Let $G$ be a connected, affine, geometrically reduced, group
> scheme of finite type over $\Spec(k)$. Then, $G(k)$ is dense in $G$.*

In particular, given Cartier's theorem (i.e. [1, Theorem 3.23]) and the fact that a field of characteristic $0$ is automatically perfect and infinite, one deduces the following:

> **Corollary:** *Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and let $G$ be an affine group scheme of finite type over $\Spec(k)$. Then, $G(k)$
> is dense in $G$.*

**References:**

[1] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Dear Alex, thank you very much. Your answer was very precise, pleasant and fulfilling! I have learned a lot! But I do have two questions: 1. Is there also a way of viewing $X(L)$ as a subset of $X$ for some extension $k \subset L \subset \overline{k}$ (where $X$ is a scheme over $k$)? For $x\in X(L)$ there can be more than on map $\varphi: k(x) \to L$ so that it does not work anymore to see $X(L)$ as a subset of $X$, right? 2. How exactly does $X(\overline{k})$ relate to $X$? Eg in hunters answer he said "$G(k)$ is a subset of $G(\overline{k})$, but how does $G(\overline{k})$ capture the

Comment: In general, how does $X(\overline{k})$ for a variety $X/k$ capture all the informations of $X$? Does it even? $X$ is more than the collection of all $X(L)$ with $k\subset L \subset \overline{k}$ for $k$-algebras $L$, or? I mean, there are still $k$-algebras like $L= \overline{k}(T)$ for a free variable $T$ or whatsoever (what I mean is that $k$-algebras do not end at $\overline{k}$). Why do some people use $X$ and $X(\overline{k}$ (for a variety $X/k$ or even more generally?) somehow interchangably? Does eg surjectivity of a morphism of varieties $G\to G'$ mean/equivalent to surjectivity of

Comment: of the map on the $\overline{k}$-points? I have once read such a similar fact for algebraic groups. Is it a general phenomenon, or how does $X(\overline{k})$ relate to $X$? I do not see it and never read anything specific about this. Such things are somehow used implicitly by the people. It would be really great to hear from you! Thank you in advance !